# ruby, rake can't convert module into string

Tags: ruby, parallel-processing, rake

I'm trying to make use of the parallel_tests gem but when I try to execute "rake parallel:create" I get an error message "can't convert Module into string".  Am I including the file wrong?  Here is my rakefile.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'cucumber'
require 'cucumber/rake/task'
require 'parallel_tests/tasks'

Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:features) do |t|
  t.profile = 'default'
end

task :default => :features
```

[image]

Comment: Why import. have you tried `import 'ParallelTests'`?

Comment: @User expected Module, got string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to include the `parallel_tests` tasks using:

```rb
require 'parallel_tests/tasks'
```

instead of your:

```rb
require 'parallel_tests'

import ParallelTests
```

(the "import" keyword is probably some DSL construct in rake that expects String and not Module?)

Comment: I've tried include ParallelTests and then it doesn't know how to build the rake task. I also tried include 'ParallelTests' and import 'ParallelTests'

Comment: if you don't have any experiance with parallel_tests what gem do you use to run parallel cucumber tests with?

Comment: I don't run them in parallel. In any case, please try the updated "recipe" (`require 'parallel_tests/tasks'`); might work better.

Comment: @MattWestlake seems you're missing `parallel` gem. Furthermore, I would strongly advise you to use Ruby 2.0 (or at least 1.9.X) because [1.8.7 is hitting end of life](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2011/10/06/plans-for-1-8-7/).

Comment: I've double checked and parallel v 0.6.5 is included in the project.  The company I work for only has rubymine v. 4.x licensing so we cannot upgrade to Ruby 2.0, and i'm currently pushing for ruby 1.9.x but we've run into some issues with it and the boss says no

Comment: @MattWestlake then try the explicit way: `gem 'parallel'` right after `require 'rubygems'`.

Comment: @MattWestlake not in your Gemfile but rather in your Rakefile.

Comment: hmm, I'm out of ideas. :-/

Comment: well +1 for trying to help me

Comment: NEED TO ADD RUBYGEMS TO THE .rb FILE IN THE PARALLEL_TESTS GEM